Node.js await .pipe()
I'm trying to read a lot of files and combine the information from them into one. Here is the implementation that I got. I want to rewrite it to .pipe(), but it only turns out to overwrite the file at each iteration. I'm asking for help.
    async joinSlices(path) {
        const wrs = new WriteStream('./bigJSON.json');
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
        for (let file of files) {
            console.log(file + ' start');
            await new Promise((res, rej) => {
                const rs = new ReadStream(path + file, 'utf-8');
                rs.on('data', (chunk) => { wrs.write(chunk); });
                rs.on('end', (data) => { console.log(file + ' end'); });
                rs.on('close', (data) => { res(); });
            });
        }
        wrs.destroy();
        console.log('write stream end');
    }

The cycle starts if both streams are declared in its body and a promise is placed at the end of recording, but overwriting occurs at each iteration.

what type of files  are you reading?

The Node.js-specific Stream API is a bit of a pain to work with. Luckily, the streams are also instances of the standardized Iteration_protocols (that are also implemented in browsers), which means you can use for await of as follows.
import fs from 'node:fs'

const inDir = 'in/'
const outFile = fs.createWriteStream('./out.json')

outFile.write('[')
let first = true
for (const fileName of fs.readdirSync(inDir)) {
  if (first) {
    first = false
  } else {
    outFile.write(',')
  }

  const file = fs.createReadStream(inDir + fileName, { encoding: 'utf-8' })
  for await (const str of file) {
    outFile.write(str)
  }
}
outFile.write(']')

outFile.close()

Or if you prefer a more functional style (with pipeline):
import fs from 'node:fs'
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises'

const inDir = 'in/'
const outFile = fs.createWriteStream('./out.json')

const iter =
  concatIterable(
    '[',
    joinIterable(
      flatMapIterable(fs.readdirSync(inDir), fileName =>
        fs.createReadStream(inDir + fileName, { encoding: 'utf-8' })
      ),
      ','
    ),
    ']',
  )

pipeline(iter, outFile).catch(console.error)

// Until https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iterator-helpers/ has landed,
// we define ourselves some helpers for Iterables, just like we have for Arrays.

async function * concatIterable (...iters) {
  for (const iter of iters) {
    yield * iter
  }
}

async function * flatMapIterable (iter, callback) {
  let i = 0
  for await (const val of iter) {
    yield * callback(val, i++)
  }
}

async function * joinIterable (iter, sep) {
  let first = true
  for await (const value of iter) {
    if (first) {
      first = false
    } else {
      yield sep
    }

    yield value
  }
}

